# c++ dynamic array problems

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, cstring

dynamic arrays are known for letting you store a string or any data type without having to declare it size
the problem that i'm facing with my c++ is the following :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
char*sentence=new char;
cout<<"enter a sentence (end with *) : ";
cin.getline(sentence,'*');
cout<<"sentence : "<<sentence<<endl;
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

the cin.getline won't stop on the character '*' so the limit will be set when i press enter.
but if i want to use only the return key it will read the first 9 characters of the string:

```
 int main()
    {
        char*sentence=new char;
        cout<<"enter a sentence : ";
        cin.getline(sentence,'\n');
            cout<<"sentence : "<<sentence<<endl;
        system("pause");
        return 0;

    }
```

but it will work only if i limit the number of characters :

```
int main()
{
char*sentence=new char;
cout<<"enter a sentence : ";
cin.getline(sentence,100,'*');
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

but i want to let the user input a sentence without limits how to do it without setting the number of characters in the cin.getline nor when declaring the dynamic array .

Comment: Allocate a buffer large enough to hold the input. Something like `char* sentence=new char[1000];`

Comment: use `std::string`. Everything else sucks.

Answer (score 3):

```
std::string line;
std::getline(std::cin, line);
```

You never have to worry about the storage in a [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), it works it all out for you.
By the way, `new char;` doesn't create a dynamic array of `char`s, it creates a pointer to just one `char`.
Also, see [`getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).

Answer (score 1):

`char* sentence=new char ;` allocates a single `char`

Use:

`char* sentence=new char[100];`

Comment: in C++, use `std::string`